# Font size on mobiles

Tags: html, css

I have a rogue bit of code for a simple paragraph that for some reason does not shrink when viewed on mobile phones.

Font size is set at 14px, yet on a phone, it displays large while the rest of the site's text is reduced to fit.

Am i missing something? Here's the page http://www.dantecreative.com/Peter

Also, on phones there is a big gap on the right hand side when view on mobile and the footer and header don't cover from left to right like they do on desktop.

Here's the CSS in question-

```
#main #mainblack #petetext p {
color:#FFFFFF;
font-size:14px;
margin-left: 60px;
font-family:Verdana, sans-serif;
line-height: 21px;
}
```

and the HTML

```
<div id="petetext">
<h1>Why Peter? Why not!</h1>
<p>
Initially attracted here by a passion for mountain biking and skiing, Dave has grown to love       Whistler for so much more – it’s incredible community of positive people who live life to the fullest. This community, coupled with Whistler’s beautiful mountains and natural environment, give this world-class resort an indescribable energy, rivaled by no other. Dave has combined this passion with knowledge, experience and effective communication and negotiating skills to become one of Whistler’s top producing agents. 
</p>
<p class="blue">
....................................................................................................................................
</p>
```

Hope someone can help. As usual, i'm sure it's something simple.

Comment: You shouldn't need to chain `IDs` like that. `#main #mainblack #petetext p`, should just be `#petetext p`

Comment: @NickR In some cases, chaining IDs can make a difference - http://jsfiddle.net/FWWN5/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
body {
    -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As Nick said you should not need that chain IDs. If what you want is to add some style to

contained in id petetex, you just need in your css: #petetex p
You can check this on this jsfiddle file[1](http://jsfiddle.net/ub8PR/1/). It works on mobile phones as well. Good luck!

```
    #petetext p{
        color:red;
        font-size:16px;
        margin-left: 60px;
        font-family:Verdana, sans-serif;
        line-height: 21px;
    }
```

Comment: Chaining ID's is more specific, so can make a difference, depending on other CSS - See http://jsfiddle.net/FWWN5/